# How to read larger data types serially with this Arduino demo?

Tags: c, arduino

I'm having a difficult time understanding how the size of my datatypes relates to parsing serial information through an Arduino mega2560. I'm trying to input large integers through the serial monitor, such as the integer 8000000, but negative numbers or numbers significantly smaller are being returned.

The following code is a demo I modified. A user must proceed and conclude serial inputs between less than and greater than signs (<'NUMBER>):

```
const byte numChars = 32;
char receivedChars[numChars];
char tempChars[numChars];        // temporary array for use by strtok() function

// variables to hold the parsed data
char messageFromPC[numChars] = {0};
int integerFromPC = 0;
float floatFromPC = 0.0;

boolean newData = false;

//============

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);
    // Serial.println("This demo expects 3 pieces of data - text, an integer and a floating point value");
    // Serial.println("Enter data in this style <text,12,24.7>  ");
    Serial.println();
}

//============

void loop() {
    recvWithStartEndMarkers();
    if (newData == true) {
        strcpy(tempChars, receivedChars);
            // this temporary copy is necessary to protect the original data
            //   because strtok() replaces the commas with \0
        parseData();
        showParsedData();
        newData = false;
    }
}

//============

void recvWithStartEndMarkers() {
    static boolean recvInProgress = false;
    static byte ndx = 0;
    char startMarker = '<';
    char endMarker = '>';
    char rc;

    while (Serial.available() > 0 && newData == false) {
        rc = Serial.read();

        if (recvInProgress == true) {
            if (rc != endMarker) {
                receivedChars[ndx] = rc;
                ndx++;
                if (ndx >= numChars) {
                    ndx = numChars - 1;
                }
            }
            else {
                receivedChars[ndx] = '\0'; // terminate the string
                recvInProgress = false;
                ndx = 0;
                newData = true;
            }
        }

        else if (rc == startMarker) {
            recvInProgress = true;
        }
    }
}

//============

void parseData() {

      // split the data into its parts
    char * strtokIndx; // this is used by strtok() as an index

    // strtokIndx = strtok(tempChars,",");      // get the first part - the string
    // strcpy(messageFromPC, strtokIndx); // copy it to messageFromPC

    strtokIndx = strtok(tempChars, ","); // this continues where the previous call left off
    integerFromPC = atoi(strtokIndx);     // convert this part to an integer

    // strtokIndx = strtok(NULL, ",");
    // floatFromPC = atof(strtokIndx);     // convert this part to a float

}

//============

void showParsedData() {
    Serial.print("Message ");
    Serial.println(messageFromPC);
    Serial.print("Integer ");
    Serial.println(integerFromPC);
    Serial.print("Float ");
    Serial.println(floatFromPC);
}
```

I suspect my problem relates to the datatypes of my variables.

Comment: What is `sizeof (int)` on the machine? If it is 16-bit that is inadequate for `8000000`. *On the Arduino Uno (and other ATmega based boards) an int stores a 16-bit (2-byte) value. This yields a range of -32,768 to 32,767 (minimum value of -2^15 and a maximum value of (2^15) - 1). On the Arduino Due and SAMD based boards (like MKR1000 and Zero), an int stores a 32-bit (4-byte) value. This yields a range of -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647 (minimum value of -2^31 and a maximum value of (2^31) - 1).*

Comment: @WeatherVane the size is 2 bytes. I'm going to change it to a datatype of 'long' and I'm going to convert 'atoi' to 'atol'.

Comment: Then you need `long` instead of `int`. Note too the `atoi` and `atol` do not need the numeric part of the string isolating from a follwoing comma: *The function stops reading the input string at the first character that it cannot recognize as part of a number.*

Comment: Yes, that worked! Thank you @WeatherVane for your help! I'm a bit embarrassed this was the mistake--it's been a long day. Thanks again!